# sql server create a duplicate order number as long as it is for 2 or more different customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **customer** table and an **order** table.

An index should be added that will not allow duplication of customer order number according to the customer

You can create a duplicate order number as long as it is for 2 or more different customers

How can such a thing be created?

Does it eliminate Identity specification ??

Comment: It has nothing to do with identity. This can easily be enforced using a composite unique index on `Customer` and `Order` columns. If you need a consecutive order number per customer, an identity column is not the answer anyway.

Comment: How is this realizable? Which columns should be added?

Comment: are you asking about the unique index or about the consecutive order number per customer? can you [edit] your question to include the [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) of the relevant tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Unique Constraint as allmhuran mentioned, also you can Create unique index on multiple columns to do that:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX IX_Order_Customer ON Order (CustomerId, OrderNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be homework.

Your answer will look something like `alter table order add constraint UniqueOrderPerCustomer unique(customer, orderNumber)`. Study [Creating Unique Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)